# Run-time error '509': this command is not available- WordBasic for Word 2013

Tags: macros, ms-word, runtime-error

I have a macro code which has following line of Wordbasic call:

```
 WordBasic.FormatFont Font:='Courier New', Points:=8
```

I have run the code, it gives runtime error 509 in this command in word 2013.
Whereas I have written individual macro in word 2013 for `wordbasic.Formatfont`, it ran absolutely fine. I don't know what is the issue behind it.

I don't find any rectifying way in google. Is there any other way to resolve wordBasic call in Microsoft Word 2013?

Answer (score 0):

*WordBasic* returns an Automation object (Word.Basic) that includes methods available in Word version 6.0. It is obsolete. Use instead Visual Basic objects and methods.

WordBasic:

```
WordBasic.FormatFont Font:='Courier New', Points:=8
```

in VBA is

```
With Selection.Font 
    .Name = "Courier New"
    .Size = 8
End With
```

This answer is not exactly what are you asking for, rather a workaround. But IMHO it is the best way - I suggest not to use WordBasic, use VBA. See [Converting WordBasic Macros to Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211926%28v=office.11%29.aspx) at msdn.com.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I am using this in my macro code of word 2013 but I am getting a new run time error '4605': this command is not available in   With Selection.Font
    .name = "Courier New"
    .Size = 8
    End With                                                                                         in .name="Courier New" line.Could you just help me out for this.\

Comment: It is strange. It looks like your previous error, but in VBA. Check please (after error appearing), if _ActiveDocument_ is your desired document, if the cursor is in supposed position and if users selection of font is possible. I guess that the document is not in supposed state.

Comment: Could you Please share How I use ActiveDocument with Selection.

Comment: _Selection_ object is actually _ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection_ object. If macro switch to another document, this new document is _ActiveDocument_. This is often source of errors. So first question: Are you sure, that you are working on desired document? Isn't closed? The _Selection_ object in _Document_ object should have a font property, I think. This is why I would inspect state of the target document.

Comment: When I am using .Name for Selection in my macro,It is automatically convert .Name into .name. Can we conclude it as a issue?

Comment: Yes I have worked on desired page.I have added VBA call of ActiveDocument in my code,but still it is showing error.

Comment: Well - I don't know, because I haven't your data and macro. As I have written previously, the _Selection_ object should have the _Font.Name_ property. Open your document, run a short test macro - works _Selection.Font.Name = "Courier New"_? If yes, then search, what part in your macro makes the change. If not, try new, empty document, and again. This is debugging and you must go through it.